# cloud run and mount a file from cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I'm running an API in cloud run and I want to know if it's possible to mount a DB file from cloud storage to my cloud run container so that I can use that DB file for querying.
For example: I have geolite database file in my cloud storage and I want to mount it everytime a new container is launched by the cloud run so I can query the location.
(This is just an example but storage file can be different like sqlite and bigger & it could be getting updated constantly by other service).

Thanks!

Comment: I think you should just use a Cloud Storage SDK to download any files you need at the time you need it.  I strongly doubt that you'll be able to mount a Cloud Storage bucket as part of the local filesystem.

Comment: I though about the downloading but during that time it will not serve the APIs and that could be the issue. It would be like cold start issue.
I though if there is any feature in cloud run like we have in AWS Lambda layer which can be directly mounted.

Comment: I don't understand the issue.  What do you mean by "it will not serve the APIs"?  You're going to have to pay the time cost of the download regardless.  Even if you were able to "mount" the bucket, it would still take time to get the file.

Comment: Also does downloading the file from storage to cloud run is counted as egress or ingress.  Just thinking if somehow I make it work by downloading the file then how much it's gonna cost. I'm new to GCP so not clear about few things. As far as I know, ingress is free.

Comment: what's the size of the db you want to use?

Comment: Around 1GB. So if there are 1000 cloud run containers running then 1000GB download from storage to cloud run.

Comment: @DougStevenson what I mean by blocking is, as soon as new container run and a new request comes, I'll not find the DB file so I'll start downloading the file. Now if my download takes 20 seconds then there will be delay in response for those request.

Comment: @Pentium10 do you have any suggestion on pricing based on the usage I updated earlier?

Comment: I would not consider download from storage an option, as that could get you into trouble. Instead as posted as answer, make it part of the container, and choose to have a minimum instance always available, this way the container is not going away as frequent.

Comment: @Pentium10  You could make it part of the container, but then you woudln't be able to get updated content dynamically if it changed over time.  That seems to be part of the requirements stated in the question.

Comment: @DougStevenson  a Geolite database doesn't change that often, mostly monthly or weekly. It can be refreshed with a new deploy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the time of the posting, there are no ways to mount a storage file in the way you requested. This is a high voted feature request.

What you can do today is:

**Split the database into segments, eg: Europe or based on IP make it a separate DB file. Leverage Cloud Run idle/minimum instances features.**

Build a container and deploy a service for each piece as a standalone API.
So in Cloud Run you will have a service for:

- EU geolite service
- APAC geolite service
- etc..

The end result is, that you don't download from Storage, instead, you have part of your container. Separating into services also helps you to scale and choose appropriate sizes. Thus if a service gets constant traffic it's always hot.

Also Cloud Run has [the concept of the idle instance](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/min-instances). You could have leverage that as well, to download from Storage and keep part of your file.

> Please understand that the container and your project size (with your
> DB file part of this) counts towards the memory limit of your Cloud
> Run service.

Answer (score 0):

You can mount cloud storage inside cloud run (container)

Here is official link from GCP.

https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/tutorials/network-filesystems-fuse